# How do I set a route for each item in the firestore list?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Please tell me how to set a route for each element from the generated firestore list. At the moment, I have a route set for all the items in the list and I do not know how to change it.

```
return ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: snapshotsub.data?.size,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final doc = docs.elementAt(index);
                      return Center(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 1, 8, 3),
                          child: Container(
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Button_Chapter_the_Articles(
                                    ButtonChapterTheArticles: ((doc.data()
                                    as Map<String, dynamic>)['testfield']
                                    as String? ?? ""),
                                    NavigatorTheChapterPageButton: const TestMain()),
                                //NewWidget()
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
```